# Changing cache update rate

Tags: order, cache, listing

Im using mylisting theme in wordpress. in listing ordering, one option is Random (cached and updated every few hours). How can I adjust the update rate from few hours to few minutes ? or even remove the caching so it randomly updates every time i refresh the page?

Comment: You'll need to check with the support team for whatever you're using that's doing the caching, whether it's your theme or (more likely) a plugin.

Comment: Thanks, will check with the support team.